# Retrieve location data from Firebase not getting on MapActivity

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

So, what I'm trying to get is `latitude` and `longitude` from my database reference path "Driver Location". But, it happens nothing but just shows normal google map without triggering to location. Please help!

```
public class StudentMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_map);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference("Driver Location");

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String lat = child.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                    String lng = child.child("longitude").getValue().toString();

                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title("Bus is here");
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

}
```

The Logcat:

```
2020-07-24 00:41:18.926 22586-22586/com.example.upmbus D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: '1df605 ', fd=100
2020-07-24 00:41:18.939 22586-23234/com.example.upmbus W/.example.upmbu: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2020-07-24 00:41:18.940 22586-23234/com.example.upmbus W/.example.upmbu: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2020-07-24 00:41:18.942 22586-23234/com.example.upmbus W/.example.upmbu: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2020-07-24 00:41:18.942 22586-23234/com.example.upmbus W/.example.upmbu: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

The database details attached

[image: This is my database structure]

Comment: @AlexMamo can you help me please?

Comment: Hi Nobel, but what's the question? And what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: The map opens but don't get the location values also not putting any marker , Just a normal map @AlexMamo

Comment: I have stored latitude and longitude successfully but can't retrieve it with the provided code avobe.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added database structure screenshot, please find the attachment

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop through the `DataSnapshot` object because you only have two properties there, and both can be accessed directly like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference driverLocationRef = rootRef.child("Driver Location");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", latitude + ", " + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
driverLocationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
3.0227801, 101.71208
```

Besides that, using:

```
String lng = child.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
```

Doesn't make any sense since both properties hold a double value and **not** a String.

Comment: com.example.upmbus D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
com.example.upmbus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.upmbus, PID: 31676
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: com.example.upmbus.StudentMapActivity$1.onDataChange(StudentMapActivity.java:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)

Comment: at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact code that you are using.